# Postman proxy authentication

Tags: proxy, postman

I am going to send a GET request in Postman desktop App from my company PC, however to do that, I should use a proxy, and I need to authenticate myself first for the proxy, but no matter how I tried, I got an error with status code 407. The funny part, that the request works when I use the web version at postman.com

This is what I tried so far:

- Under Settings I tried to set the "use the system proxy" - did not worked
- Under settings I added a Custom Proxy with my credentials, got a message: "Error: tunneling socket could not be established, statusCode=407
  "
- I tried to add my credentials with encoded format in the Header as a "Proxy-Authorization" value - didn't work
- I created a batch file with the following data, placed it inside the following directory ((C:\Users\myUsername\AppData\Local\Postman\app-10.15.0)) and started Postman with this file  but didn't worked:

```
set HTTPS PROXY=http://myUsername:myPassword@proxyUrl:Port
set HTTP PROXY=http://myUsername:myPassword@proxyUrl:Port
set http PROXY=http://myUsername:myPassword@proxyUrl:Port
set https PROXY=http://myUsername:myPassword@proxyUrl:Port
SET NO_PROXY=localhost,127.0.0.1
START %LOCALAPPDATA%\Postman\Update.exe --processStart "Postman.exe"
```

Comment: Best way is to ask your colleague! In my case, [I don't have to provide any credentials](https://i.stack.imgur.com/963QB.png)